# counting elements in xml with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby

I'd like to understand why `count` gives me `5`?

If I'm at the root element and I want to know my children, it is supposed to give me `2`.

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open('link..to....element.xml'))
root = doc.root.children.count
puts root



<element>
  <name>Married with Children</name>
  <name>Married with Children</name>
</element>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You get `5` as the result because there are five child nodes under the root `<element>` node. There are two `<name>` nodes and three text nodes that each consist of whitespace; one between the opening `<element>` and the first `<name>`, one between the two `<names>`, and one between the second `<name>` and the closing `</element>`:

```ruby
doc.root.children.each do |c|
  p c
end
```

output:

```
#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x80544a04 "\n  ">
#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x80544900 name="name" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x8054470c "Married with Children">]>
#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x80544554 "\n  ">
#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x80544478 name="name" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x80544284 "Married with Children">]>
#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x805440cc "\n">
```

If you use the `noblanks` option when parsing Nokogiri won’t include these whitespace nodes:

```ruby
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open('link..to....element.xml')) { |c| c.noblanks }
```

Now `doc.root.children.count` will equal `2`, only the two `<name>` element nodes will be included.

Comment: finally!!! I couldn't understand why each "datas" still repeats 8 times (in my real documents not the example that I gave). thks!